# History of the curved exponential family

Tags: probability, exponential-family, history

Does anyone know the first person who introduced the curved exponential family and also which paper it was first presented?

I vaguely remember that it might be Fisher who wrote about it in a paper on  probability theory, but I can not locate the paper it was published.

Comment: [Efron (1975)](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aos/1176343282) does not cite anyone else when introducing the term (p.1192).

Comment: @Xi'an thank you!